# WiX Custom Action in Javascript - How to make web requests?

Tags: javascript, wix, custom-action

I have a Custom Action in WiX (windows installer toolset) that is written in Javascript. What are my options to make web requests? As far as I know, `fetch` is a web api which is not accessible in the runtime provided by the windows installer. Is there a way to import third-party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft JScript (which is what is run in WiX custom actions) provides native web requests like this:

```
// Instantiate a WinHttpRequest object.
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
```

`WinHttpRequest` can then be used similar to XMLHttpRequest.

[see documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/retrieving-data-using-script)